# k-nearest-neighbor classifier in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, classification

I'm completely new to the k-nearest neighbor classifier algorithm. Can someone please give me a link to a good tutorial/lecture that gives a dataset so that I can apply k-nearest neighbor to it.

I really really need to learn this but due to lack of examples it's making this task very difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend the [**Iris plant dataset**](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris).

> This is perhaps the best known database to be found in the pattern recognition literature. Fisher's paper is a classic in the field and is referenced frequently to this day. (See Duda & Hart, for example.) The data set contains 3 classes of 50 instances each, where each class refers to a type of iris plant. One class is linearly separable from the other 2; the latter are NOT linearly separable from each other.

Comment: @Nathan: If you have the statistics toolbox, you can get the iris dataset in Matlab via `load fisheriris`

Comment: thanks for the dataset. I would also like if someone could post a link to a tutorial that properly explains how to use knn in matlab. Please.

Comment: Assuming you have the bioinformatics toolbox, [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html) seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Nathan, did the dataset help?